# Tensorflow padding error: paddings must be no greater than the dimension size: 62, 61 greater than 5

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to pad my tensor from shape (1, 5, 256) to (1, 128, 256). When I try the below code with constants 0 then it works.

```
tensor = tf.expand_dims(image_output, axis=1)
logg = tf.constant([ [0, 0] ,     [62, 61],    [0, 0]   ])
new_tensor = tf.pad(tensor, logg, mode ='CONSTANT', constant_values=0)
```

However when I try with SYMMETRIC or REFLECT method like below

```
tensor = tf.expand_dims(image_output, axis=1)
logg = tf.constant([[0, 0], [62, 61], [0, 0]])
new_tensor = tf.pad(image_embeddings, logg, mode ='SYMMETRIC')
```

it generates this error `Node: 'MirrorPad' paddings must be no greater than the dimension size: 62, 61 greater than 5 [[{{node MirrorPad}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_463079]`

Comment: As the error says, if the dimension is 5, how can you reflect it to a higher size like 62?. Define how you want to pad the values?.

Comment: So it can't be pad to a higher value than 5?

Comment: We can't use the above function, but you can try repeat or concat if you know how you want to pad the array.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible with repetition.

Answer (score 1):

that is because padding of the target dimension is the result of the padding input array, see my example the function allowed that's because matches the shape size. ( Matrixes dimensions )

Sample: Matrixes is the name of the clock when it counters it creates new dimensions.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
file = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy\\15.tif"
image = tf.io.read_file( file )
image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
image = tf.image.resize(image, [256, 256], method='nearest')

print( image.shape )

############################################################################
paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0], [64, 64], [0, 0]])
image = tf.pad(image, paddings, "SYMMETRIC")
print( image.shape )
############################################################################

plt.imshow( image )
plt.show()
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOq4g.png)